# Is it safe to iterate over an unchanging dictionary from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I've got code like this that's executed from many threads simultaneously (over shared `a` and `b` objects of type `Dictionary<int, double>`):

```
foreach (var key in a.Keys.Union(b.Keys)) {
    dist += Math.Pow(b[key] - a[key], 2);
}
```

The dictionaries don't change during the lifetime of the threads. Is this safe? So far, it seems OK, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: On a somewhat relevant note: if dictionaries don't change, then why calculate the same thing over and over?

Comment: Good point - my guess is that Cameron's threads are fire-and-forget worker threads.  But that's just a guess.  So perhaps he's loading his data and then calling a bunch of worker threads to process them and then moving onto the next data point.

Comment: @liho1eye: Good point, but I left out some context: I've got a large number of (unchanging) dictionaries, of which I take certain pairs and pass them to a function (having as parameters `a` and `b`), where `a` and `b` never repeat as parameters (so I'm never repeating a calculation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [dictionary documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

As long as you're never writing, it should be safe.

Answer (score 6):

### Only if You Guarantee No Writes Occur

> A Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) can support multiple readers
> concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so,
> enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
> procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write
> accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration.
> To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading
> and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see ConcurrentDictionary(Of TKey,
> TValue).
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
> safe.

### Sources

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: So how is that a "no"? That is positively "yes" given the assumption in the OP.

Comment: I'll revise the heading - Reed beat me to the copy/paste anyway.

Comment: It was specified that "the dictionaries don't change during the lifetime of the threads."  While this answer is true, for the case in question the answer is actually "Yes."

Comment: Who posted first is irrelevant (though people do tend to upvote answer they see first) as long as the answer is correct and complete.